# How does a REST server with Shiro authentication identify a given HTTP request as being part of a given session

Tags: java, rest, shiro

In other words, if a user on a given machine makes an RESTful call to a server which logs them in, and then, subsequently, makes a separate, second call which requires them to be logged in, what component of that request identifies them as the same entity which previously had logged in?  Why, if they make the request from (for example) a different browser, are the identified as a separate entity?

I know that it is the Session object which the Java code uses to hold information about the set of requests, and the Subject contains information about the user who is logged in.  What I can't figure out is what mechanism Shiro uses to generate the Session object returned by .getSession(false) and the Subject returned by .getSubject().  I assume that it's sent somewhere in the headers, but I'm not sure where.  I feel like I'm missing something which should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on how you setup Shiro, but typically it comes down to how your sessions are managed on your servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc).